# jQuery ajax request with different types of responses to handle

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am submitting a form through `$.ajax()` method. My request is like this:

```
       $.ajax(url, {
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "html json",
            data: formData,
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
            }
        }).done(function (result) {
                //handle correct json response or html response
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown.stack);
        });
```

When the server returns a JSON response, all works as excpected. But when the response is Html, the `fail()` callback is executed (status code of the response is 200 - OK) and errorThrown.stack as this value:

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at jQuery.extend.parseJSON (http://localhost/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:550:23)
    at ajaxConvert (http://localhost/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:8429:19)
    at done (http://localhost/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:8185:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback (http://localhost/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:8778:8)"
```

So I think its is trying to parse JSON instead of html. I don't understand because I have set the `dataType` option to `"html json"`...

Following are some info about the request/response:

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:pt-PT,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2386
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control:private, s-maxage=0
Content-Length:56392
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 03 Oct 2014 09:52:13 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:4.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Why is this happening?

**Solution** (based on @Oscar Bout response)

```
        $.ajax(url, {
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "html",
            data: formData,
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
            }
        }).done(function (result) {
            try {
                var jsonResult = $.parseJSON(result);
                //handle json result
            } catch (e) {
                $("#myDiv").html(result); //handle html result
            }
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown.stack);
        });
```

I think using `try/catch` is not the best approach so I am listening other options.

Comment: Did you analyze the actual request and response (e.g. using the browser's Web Console) and check the actual return type of the response (`Content-Type`)?

Comment: @JanakaBandara I updated my question why the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your are saying in the dataType is "treat the html response as JSON".

2 values in the dateType function does not mean it can handle 2 types.
It means "treat first one as second".

So the error is sadly correct. When html comes in, it is treated as JSON.
Parse that and well... since it is not JSON but in fact HTML it fails.

The function is meant for "syntax correct json but with a html header".
Your response probably is "syntax correct html with html header", hence the "<" in your output.

Maybe for you there is a way around using a **try {} catch (e) {}** function?

Here the dataType explanation:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I misunderstood the use of `dataType`. I will update my question with the solution based on this response, but I think using `try/catch` is not the best approach, so I am listening for other solutions...